# Tab Bar Application, one UITableViewController with different data

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, nib

I have a Tab bar App with four tabs. Each tab loads the same UITableViewController.

I would like to fill the table based on which tab is tapped.

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) ...
```

Etc.